# can't access application on port 80

Tags: docker, discourse

I have Discours installed. It runs on Docker. It is running on port 80 and 443. But when I access my domain [www.devplace.be](http://www.devplace.be), it can't access the server. The domain is pointed to the server (A record with the correct IP address).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Flush your local DNS records.
- Change your local DNS resolver

You either have the record cached locally,pointing to an old/wrong address, or it was not propagated to your resolver yet.

It works on my side :)

[image]